# How to fix 'TypeError: process.hrtime is not a function' in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, aws-amplify, nativescript-angular

I am building a nativescript (+Angular) app with aws-amplify. Particular while using the S3 Storage API from aws-amplify, I get following error:

```
AWSS3Provider - get signed url error TypeError: process.hrtime is not a function. (In 'process.hrtime()', 'process.hrtime' is undefined)
```

I am using the following `polyfills`

```
(window as any).global = window;
(window as any).process = {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined },
};
```

In my code, I check if process is not undefined.

```
        if(typeof process !== 'undefined') {
        Storage.get('fileassets/asset.txt')
            .then(result => alert(result))
            .catch(err => alert(err));
        } else {
            alert("process is undefined");
        }
```

There is no alert raised, but it seems the native code S3Provider relies on process.hrtime, that can't be resolved in nativescript  non{N} environment

I expect that aws-amplify API is successfully executed, as It have no control to hack that to avoid calling process.hrtime.

Comment: **{N} !== Node**, not all node libraries work with NativeScript but only CommonJS ones. You should consider using the native libraries for iOS / Android.